# Loosen Thule Axle adaptor + hub adaptor

Tags: trailer

I recently changed my bike and need to migrate the Thule trailer axle kit. However I am unable to loosen the axle adaptor from the hub gear adaptor.

These products:

- https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B07NZ6C356
- https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Thule-axle-coupling-full/dp/B015DJN2AM

[image]

E.g. these two components are fused together it seems with no way to loosen it to align the adaptor.

Any advice? I've tried a spanner and a wrench to try and turn them but they just won't budge. Should I just buy another two bits?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something has secured the bolt into the thread.  It could be intentional with a threadlocker product like locktite, or a similar process caused by rust.  If one part is aluminium and another is steel, it could be galvanic corrosion caused by dissimilar metals in contact, and exacerbated by a lack of assembly lube/grease.

You have options:

1. buy a new hitch - this would let you tow the trailer with either bike.   Or if you plan to sell the old bike, its an upgrade like a towball on a car.  Downside, this has the most cost.
2. Leverage - First spray penetrating oil at the threads where possible and let it sit for a day.   Put the tall nut into a stout bench vise, and clean up the bolt head using a wire brush.  You might need a file to knock down any high spots, burrs, or damage.
   Use a 6 pointed socket or a ring spanner of the correct size on the bolthead.  If that doesn't work...
3. Judicious use of heat.  Start with a hot air gun and gently warm the whole part to around 100-200 degrees C.  You can try spraying with penetrating oil too, the thermal shock can help though avoid breathing the steam vapours.  This is below ignition temperature so risk of fire is low.  Wear gloves and eye protection.
4. Destructive - either way you're gonna need a new bolt+nut

   a. Excessive use of heat.   Gas torch to cut the bolt off.  Try and save the holder

   b. Grinder to cut the bolt off.  Avoid nicking the holder

If the funds permit, I'd recommend option 1, and get a towhitch for every bike that might need to tow the trailer, and a spare.

On assembly, do use copper clay or grease or something to make this job easier for the next person, who might be you in 5 years.

Comment: Thanks for such an informative post! After spending another hour or so trying to loosen it I realised opting for point 1 seems the most sensible thing at this time.